# using javascript jQuery.post() to open a window

Tags: javascript, facebook, jquery

in order to do a facebook invite automation i need to post specific data so that the facebook friend selection will open.
ill use this script on an already open event.
i think i just dont get the post() method, or it not used the way i want it.
im trying to run directly from the browser the method like this:

`javascript:$.post('/events/create.php',{/ajax/choose/?type: 'event' eid: 'someeventid' send_invites_on_close: '1'});`

or:

`javascript:$.post('/events/create.php?eid=someeventid',{/ajax/choose/?type: 'event' eid: 'someeventid' send_invites_on_close: '1'});`

any ideas?

thanks!

edit:

the html behind the post is:

`<a class="mbs uiButton" role="button" href="/events/create.php?eid=*eventid*" rel="dialog-post" ajaxify="/ajax/choose/?type=event&amp;eid=*eventid*&amp;send_invites_on_close=1"><i class="mrs img sp_a2jb2c sx_c44d3d"></i><span class="uiButtonText">Select Guests to Invite</span></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of formatting parameters to JQuery post is like this (you were close, but need the commas to separate params) :

```
$.post("/events/create.php", { /ajax/choose/?type: 'event', eid: 'someeventid', send_invites_on_close: '1' });
```

(PS : not sure about whether your first param is legit without testing either - not sure about the special chars in there)

Comment: the html is: `<a class="mbs uiButton" role="button" href="/events/create.php?eid=*eventid*" rel="dialog-post" ajaxify="/ajax/choose/?type=event&amp;eid=*eventid*&amp;send_invites_on_close=1"><i class="mrs img sp_a2jb2c sx_c44d3d"></i><span class="uiButtonText">Select Guests to Invite</span></a>` the above doesnt work, i guess the params are wrong.